# The `npm pkg` package is unable to scan directories/assets/scripts

Tags: node.js, npm, executable

I'm using `pkg` to compile a simple nodejs application into an executable.  My code runs fine with `npm start`, but my code fails when I run the compiled executable, because I get this error:

```
Unable to scan directory: Error: ENOENT: no such file or directory, scandir '/home/john/project/src/programs'
```

I'll share my simple `helloworld` program so you can repeat the experiment yourself:

This is my `/home/john/project/package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "helloworld",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "main": "index.js",
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./src/hello.js"
  },
  "dependencies": {},
  "devDependencies": {
    "nodemon": "^3.0.1",
    "pkg": "^5.8.1"
  },
  "pkg": {
    "assets": [
      "./src/programs/*.js"
    ],
    "scripts": [
      "./src/programs/*.js"
    ]
  }
}
```

This is my `/home/john/project/src/hello.js`

```
const path = require('path');
const fs = require('fs');

const directoryPath = path.join(process.cwd(), 'src', 'programs');
console.log(directoryPath);
const run = async (err, programs) => {
    try {
        if (err) {
            console.log(`Unable to scan directory: ${err}`);
            return;
        }

        for (let c = 0; c < programs.length; c += 1) {
            const programFile = programs[c].replace(/\.js$/, '');
            const { program } = require(`${process.cwd()}/src/programs/${programFile}`);
            await program();
        }
    } catch (e) {
        console.log('Error: ', e.toString());
    }
};

fs.readdir(directoryPath, run);
```

This is my `/home/john/project/src/programs/world.js`

```
module.exports.program = async () => {
  console.log('hello world');
};
```

I get success when I run these commands:

```
cd /home/john/project;
npm start;
# SUCCESS - result is `hello world` prints to stdout
```

However, I get the error mentioned above if I run these commands:

```
cd /home/john/project;
./node_modules/.bin/pkg ./src/hello.js -o hello --targets node12-linux-x64;
# temporarily move the `src/programs` out of the way to ensure the binary can't access it and confirm if it's already part of binary
mv src/programs ../;
./hello;
# FAILURE - I get the error message mentioned at beginning of this post
```

What did I do wrong?

---

NOTE: I have tried replacing `process.cwd()` with `__dirname`, but this gave me different sets of errors.  I've tried different values in the `package.json : {"pkg":{...}}` but still couldn't get it to work